# How list controls stored in assembly in code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, reflection, controls

I have project containing few user controls (each represents a game, but that's irrelevant), in the second project (the game client) I want to list controls that are in that first library, create their objects and attach that control to a container. How can I do that?

These are WPF projects. Please note that I don't want to use VS toolbox, as that library will be independently updated, while the client not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine all your control inherit from the Control class, you can do that

```
   List<Type> res = new List<Type>();
        foreach (Type aType in   Assembly.LoadFile("yourdll.dll").GetTypes())
        {
            if(aType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Control)))
                res.Add(aType);
        }
```

So you'll get all your type in the res list.

EDIT

And like that you can create your instance

```
 Control myControl = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(aType);
```

Comment: that's very nice ;) can you provide an example how to create now object of that type?